# How to get the order items and quote items whenever create order from admin panel?

Tags: magento-2.1, sales-order, quote, quoteitem

I would like to get the items that added via admin panel in the order page.
I have created the observer to listen to `Create New Order` button event like this :

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    /** @var OrderInterface $order */
    $order = $event->getOrder();
    /** @var OrderItemInterface[] $orderItems */
    $orderItems = $order->getItems();

    /** @var Quote $quote */
    $quote = $event->getQuote();
    /** @var  CartInterface[] $quoteItems */
    $quoteItems = $quote->getItems();

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $logger= $objectManager->create('\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface');
    $logger->debug('Fabelio Observer::');
    $logger->debug('Fabelio Observer:: item id = ' . $quoteItems[0]->getId());
    $logger->debug('Fabelio Observer:: order item sku ' . $orderItems[0]->getSku());

    $this->quoteSubmitBeforeProcess->processSales($quoteItems,$orderItems);

    return $this;
}
```

When I try to create new order in the admin panel I got :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getId() on null

Now I know that the `$quoteItems = $quote->getItems();` giving me a null value.

So How to get the quote items and order items from admin here ? I successfully getting the data from front-end side but not in the admin side .

Comment: Which event you are using ?

Comment: `sales_model_service_quote_submit_before` this event.

Comment: Could you please try with `$quote->getAllItems()` and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve my own problem here, it looks like the

```
/** @var Quote $quote */
    $quote = $event->getQuote()
```

is empty during create new order via admin panel. so getting the order event and then get the sku for each item that ordered from admin is the way to do this. here is the working solution :

- create the events.xml in the adminhtml :

  ```
  <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
      <observer name="fab_quote_submit_before_admin" instance="Fabelio\Checkout\Observer\OrderSubmitBeforeObserver" />
  </event>
  ```
- and create the observer like this :

  ```
  class OrderSubmitBeforeObserver implements ObserverInterface
  {
  /**
   * @var OrderSubmitBeforeProcess
   */
  private $orderSubmitBeforeProcess;


  public function __construct(
      OrderSubmitBeforeProcess $orderSubmitBeforeProcess
  )
  {
      $this->orderSubmitBeforeProcess= $orderSubmitBeforeProcess;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function execute(Observer $observer)
  {
      $event = $observer->getEvent();
      /** @var OrderInterface $order */
      $order = $event->getOrder();
      /** @var OrderItemInterface[] $orderItems */
      $orderItems = $order->getItems();

      $this->orderSubmitBeforeProcess->process($orderItems);

      return $this;
  }
  }
  ```

that's it.